# setAttribute doesn't affect toString of containing element

Tags: perl, xml-attribute, xml-libxml

This prints 100 WOWs, but not a single WOW in the toString. Why?

```
for my $node ( $body->findnodes('//a') ) {
    $node->setAttribute( 'href', "WOW" );
}
for my $node ( $body->findnodes('//a') ) {
    print $node->getAttribute('href');
}

print $body->toString(2);
```

Comment: What type of object is $body, and what is the data it's accessing.

Comment: You search for `a` elements in the entire document (because you used  `//a` instead of `.//a` or `descendant::a`), and it's possible there are 100 `a` elements in the document, but that none that are descendants of `$body`. But we can't tell for sure, because you didn't demonstrate the problem you are having. Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem. (See [mcve].)

Comment: Note that preceding your snippet with `use XML::LibXML; my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string('<body><a></a><a></a></body>'); my $body = $doc;` or `use XML::LibXML; my $doc = XML::LibXML->new->parse_string('<body><a></a><a></a></body>'); my ($body) = $doc->findnodes('body');` does not yield the output you claim.

Answer (score 0):

As described [in the comment from Ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642855/setattribute-doesnt-affect-tostring-of-containing-element#comment92218386_52642855):

> You search for a elements in the entire document (because you used //a
>   instead of .//a or descendant::a), and it's possible there are 100 a
>   elements in the document, but that none that are descendants of $body

typing `'.//a'` instead of `'//a'` is the correct way here.